# Draw a finite state machine which will accept the regular expression $(a^2)^* + (b^3)^*$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-expressions

Draw a finite state machine which will accept the regular expression:

$(a^2)^* + (b^3)^*$

In particular, I am confused by the $+$ sign, what does it exactly mean? Most literature I could find about $+$ is $a^+$, which means 1 or more $a$; but here it is clearly not the same meaning.

Comment: $+$ means union. There are good mathematical reasons to use this notation. In particular $(A^*, +, .)$ is a semiring.

Comment: Thx for the comment. Can u show me the graph of union?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start at state $q_{0}$. On input of $a$, transition to state $q_{1}$. On input of $b$, go to $q_{2}$.

While on $q_{1}$, if there is an input of $a$, go to $q_{0}$.

While on $q_{2}$, if an input of $b$, go to $q_{3}$. On $q_{3}$, on input of $b$, go to $q_{4}$. While on $q_{4}$, go to $q_{2}$ on input of $b$.

The accepting states are $q_{0}$ and $q_{4}$. Of course, you could have $q_{0}$ and $q_{4}$ go to a separate accepting state on input $\epsilon$, the empty string.

Comment: So for $q2, q3, q4$, they will not get input of $a$, and $q1$ will not get input of $b$?

Comment: If there is an input of $a$ for states $q_{2}, q_{3}, q_{4}$, go to the rejecting state. The same for an input of $b$ on $q_{1}$. An input of the empty string on states $q_{1}, q_{2}, q_{3}$ should transition to the reject state as well.

Comment: So another state q5 to represent reject state?

Comment: Yes. Automaton that don't accept everything have a reject state.

Comment: That makes sense. I will mark yours as correct answer unless someone else comes up with reasons not to

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect, since it would accept $aabbb$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the drawing:

[image: FA]

The idea is that the machine has two counters, one for `a`s and one for `b`s, indicated by the orange boxes.  Since it accepts *either* a number of `a`s that is a multiple of 2, *or* a number of `b`s that is a multiple of 3, it only needs to choose which of these counters to use.  Upon seeing the first symbol in the input, either `a` or `b`, it chooses which of the counters to use, and thereafter circulates around the counter.  One state of each counter is an accepting state.  If the wrong symbol appears while the machine is counting, it goes into ‘dead’ state $x$, from which it cannot escape; transitions to state $x$ are drawn in red.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's similar to the notation used in [this post on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions/2017#2017), where the author uses it to mean OR.

Applying to your example, your FSM must accept an even number of `a`s, or a number of `b`s divisible by three.

So, to draw the graph, first draw the graph for $(a^2)^*$.  Then, draw the graph for $(b^3)^*$.  Then, put a start state, say $s$, and transitions consuming the empty string from $s$ to the two graphs.

Comment: How about `baabbb`? Could you show me the full graph? I worked out one version but it seems very confusing.

Comment: If that is what it means, the regular expression is (aa)*|(bbb)*